# Can't attach CircleCI Workspace from Windows to Linux due to "Cannot change ownership to uid 3434"

Tags: tar, circleci, workspace

I am using CircleCI's persistent workspace feature to run jobs with the same build folder between Linux and Windows executor types. I was able to go from Linux to Windows but when I went from Windows to Linux I got this error when CircleCI attempted to attach the workspace.

Applying workspace layers:

```
  9ba3eddc-3658-43c2-858b-aea39250af3e
  25c476af-8804-4125-b979-05a62a9ac204

Error applying workspace layer for job 25c476af-8804-4125-b979-05a62a9ac204: Error extracting tarball /tmp/workspace-layer-25c476af-8804-4125-b979-05a62a9ac204854634413 : tar: project/.circleci/config.yml: Cannot change ownership to uid 3434, gid 197121: Invalid argument
```

Looking at the error it's clear that the UIDs are not existing on the system. I attempted to run commands to create the same UID/GID it was erroring on but I still got an unable to change owner issue.

I was expecting CircleCI to move the files and ignore the user: group part when it was extracted as you can't guarantee the UID/GID exists.
I opened a support ticket but hoping for a faster solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue and it's forcing CircleCI to use TAR_OPTIONS environment variable to force the options to ignore the owner/group. 
Here is what I added to my jobs steps that attach the workspace when the previous job run was Window.

```
build-app:
    build:
    docker:
      - image: Dockerhub.com/myrepo/myimage:1.0.0
        environment:
          TAR_OPTIONS: --no-same-owner
```

using TAR_OPTIONS environment to inject the option `--no-same-owner` allowed CircleCI to extract the tarball without issue.